# Showing that a basis spans the exterior product space $\bigwedge^k(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I choose $\{e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_k}:i_1 < \cdots <i_k \}$ to be my basis for the exterior product space $\bigwedge^k(V)$  where $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ is the standard basis for the vector space $V$.  I would like to prove that this is a basis.  Linear independence is easy, but spanning seems like a massive undertaking.  Suppose I take any arbitrary vector $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$ in my exterior product space, and I wish to express this vector in terms of the basis elements above.  It seems like I have a massive chain of sums and products to deal with here.  Is there any way to simplify the computations?  How would you do this?

Comment: If you already know what the basis is for the $k$-fold tensor product, you can use the image of that basis under the quotient map into the exterior algebra as a spanning set of $\bigwedge^k(V)$. Then it should be pretty easy to see the candidate basis you have above is indeed a basis of the exterior product.

Comment: The element $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$ isn't an arbitrary $k$-vector.  An arbitrary $k$-vector would be a sum of $k$-vectors of this form (what you have is called a $k$-blade).

Answer (score 3):

As a comment above said, not every $v \in \bigwedge^kV$ can be written in the form $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$.  However, every vector can be written as a linear combination of vectors of this form. It therefore suffices to show that every $v$ of that form (i.e. every $k$-blade) can be expressed as a linear combination of your basis.

With that, suppose that $v_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{ij} e_i$.  We can then write
$$
v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k = 
\left(\sum_{i_1=1}^n \alpha_{i_11}e_i\right) \wedge \cdots \wedge \left(\sum_{i_k=1}^n \alpha_{i_kk}e_i\right)
$$
By multilinearity, expand this into
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i_1,\dots,i_k \leq n} \alpha_{i_11}\cdots\alpha_{i_kk}(e_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k})
$$
Now, using the alternating property of the wedge product, why is this ultimately a linear combination of your basis vectors?

Comment: I struggle with your statement "However, every vector can be written as a linear combination of vectors of this form". How do we know that to be true?

Comment: @Azur This essentially comes down to the definition of the exterior product.